# How can I protect a .so I am embedding in my .apk file?

Tags: android, c++, apk, shared-objects

My .apk contains a .so along with the .dex file.  How can I prevent someone from stealing my .so file?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. All files inside an apk file can be easily decompiled/unpacked.
Either you encrypt your local apk file or you store them on a server and load them at runtime.
But, there will be never a 100% protection.